# Strengthening of Freiman's theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Is the following strengthening of Freiman's theorem true?

Let $G$ be an abelian group. We say that a set $X\subset G$ is $d$-structured if $X$ is a union of $d$ or less $d$--dimensional (generalized) arithmetic progressions.

For every $C, \varepsilon > 0$ there exists $d=d(C, \varepsilon)$ such that for every sets $A, B \subset G$ of cardinality $n$ satisfying $|A+B|\leq Cn$, there exist $d$--structured sets $A'\supset A, B'\supset B$ such that $|A'+B'|\leq (C+\varepsilon)n$.

Maybe one should also allow intersections of arithmetic progressions?